# VB.net insert url into firefox url bar

Tags: vb.net, winforms, firefox, pinvoke

i tried to insert url into firefox url bar.

my code:

Imports:

```
Imports NDde.Client
```

code:

```
Dim dde As DdeClient = New DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_GetWindowInfo")
dde.Connect()
Dim url As String = dde.Request("URL", Integer.MaxValue)
dde.Disconnect()
```

this code **return**(get) the url.

how can i **insert** url?

(i tried to use dde.Handle and findwindowex, but i dont know what is the classname of the url bar(yes, i tried spy++))

Comment: Do you want to open the url or do you just want to put text in the url bar?

Comment: i want just replace the current url with my url and then navigate.

Comment: @Fumf Same thing I Want to do with firefox. Have you found the solution of this problem? If yes, so please post your answer here and help us. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
'///Download NDDE library from here "http://ndde.codeplex.com/"
'///Then add refrence NDde.dll in your project.

Imports NDde.Client 'import NDde Client

Button1 Click:

Dim dde As New DdeClient("Firefox", "WWW_OpenURL") 'you can also use "Opera" instead of "Firefox"
dde.Connect()
Dim url As String = dde.Request("http://www.google.com", Integer.MaxValue) 'you can replace google.com with your desired URL.
dde.Disconnect()
```

It will set URL in firefox or opera browsers URL bar and navigates it. Hope This will helpfull to you.